# Assigning to .self in reference class initialize

Tags: r, reference-class

I'm trying to define a hybrid `initialize` function that can either takes a numeric argument or an object of the same class (similar to "copy-constructor" in other languages). My attempt:

```
    setRefClass("Temp",
        fields=list(
          x="numeric",
          y="ANY"),
        methods=list(initialize=function(object){
          if (class(object) == "numeric"){
            .self$x <- object
            .self$y <- NULL
          }
          else if (class(object) == "Temp"){
            print("Copy")
            .self <- object
            #.self <- object$copy()
          }
          else{
            stop(paste0("Class '",class(object),"' unknown"))
          }
        }
        ))
```

So if `object` is numeric, it is assigned to `.self$x` and `.self$y` is initialized to `NULL`. If `object` has class `"Temp"`, then `initialize` should construct a deep copy of `object`.

However, `.self <- object` doesn't do anything. If I run

```
    temp1 <- new("Temp",1)
    temp2 <- new("Temp",temp1)
```

Then `temp2` is initialized to default values. If instead I use `.self <- object$copy()`, then I get

```
    Error in .Object$initialize(...) : argument "object" is missing, with no default
```

which probably happens because `$copy()` calls `initialize()`.

What is the correct code for what I tried to achieve with `.self<-object`?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you need reference classes? They’re generally seen as obsolete and their use is discouraged. If you really need reference semantics, check out R6, which is a modern replacement of RC. But in most cases there’s no need for that either.

Comment: I am interested in a solution using reference classes.